# Understanding dense layer in LSTM architecture (labels & logits)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working through this notebook -- https://github.com/aamini/introtodeeplearning/blob/master/lab1/solutions/Part2_Music_Generation_Solution.ipynb -- where we are using an embedding layer, LSTM, and final dense layer w/ softmax to generate music.

I'm a little confused, however, on how we're calculating loss; it is my understanding that in this notebook (in compute_loss()), in any given batch, we are comparing expected labels (which are the notes themselves) to the logits (i.e. predictions from the dense layer). However, aren't these predictions supposed to be a probability distribution? When are we actually selecting the label that we are predicting against?

A little more clarification on my question: if the shape of our labels is (batch_size, # of time steps), and the shape of our logits is (batch_size, # of time steps, vocab_size), at what point in the compute_loss() function are we actually selecting a label for each time step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the Keras loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy()` does everything you need.

At each timestep of the LSTM model, the top dense layer and softmax function inside that loss function together generate a probability distribution over the model's vocabulary, which in this case are musical notes. Suppose the vocabulary comprises the notes A, B, C, D. Then one possible probability distribution generated is: `[0.01, 0.70, 0.28, 0.01]`, meaning that the model is putting a lot of probability on note B (index 1), like so:

```
Label:    A     B     C     D
----      ----  ----  ----  ----
Index:    0     1     2     3
----      ----  ----  ----  ----
Prob:     0.01  0.70  0.28  0.01
```

Suppose the true note should be C, which is represented by the number 2, since it is at index 2 in the distribution array (with indexing starting at 0). To measure the difference between the predicted distribution and the true value distributions, use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy()` function to produce a floating-point number representing the loss.

More information can be found on [this TensorFlow documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy). On that page, they have the example:

```py
y_true = [1, 2]
y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

You can see in that example there is a batch of two instances. For the first instance, the true label is `1` and the predicted distribution is `[0.05, 0.95, 0]`, and for the second instance, the true label is `2` while the predicted distribution is `[0.1, 0.8, 0.1]`.

This function is used in your Jupyter Notebook in section 2.5:

> To train our model on this classification task, we can use a form of the crossentropy loss (negative log likelihood loss). Specifically, we will use the sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss, as it utilizes integer targets for categorical classification tasks. We will want to compute the loss using the true targets -- the labels -- and the predicted targets -- the logits.

So to answer your questions directly:

> it is my understanding that in this notebook (in compute_loss()), in any given batch, we are comparing expected labels (which are the notes themselves) to the logits (i.e. predictions from the dense layer).

Yes, your understanding is correct.

> However, aren't these predictions supposed to be a probability distribution?

Yes, they are.

> When are we actually selecting the label that we are predicting against?

It is done inside the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy()` function. If your distribution is `[0.05, 0.95, 0]`, then that implicitly means that the function is predicting 0.05 probability for index 0, 0.95 probability for index 1, and 0.0 probability for index 3.

> A little more clarification on my question: if the shape of our labels is (batch_size, # of time steps), and the shape of our logits is (batch_size, # of time steps, vocab_size), at what point in the compute_loss() function are we actually selecting a label for each time step?

It's inside that function.